# I'm using Rails 2.3.14 and Rake 10.0.2 is not running, how can I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

I am using Rails 2.3.14 and Ruby 1.8.7 (used RVM to install them) but my default set is Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3. I created an empty gemset but when I list the gems available I get this:

```
gem list --local

bundler (1.2.3)
rake (10.0.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
```

So I just went ahead and created a Rails 2.3.14 app and wanted to create my database by running:

```
raked db:create
```

and I get this

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rake/rdoctask
../Rakefile:8:in `require'
../Rakefile:8
../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My Rakefile is

```
require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'

require 'tasks/rails'
```

So how can I fix this problem? I'm guessing it's the rake version (mine is currently 10.0.2) from what I read the version of rake commonly used with the Rails 2.3 seires is 0.9.+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `require 'rake/rdoctask'` do `require 'rdoc/task'`

rdoctask was deprecated quite a while ago